# Bootstrap and jQuery error: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap collapse component and just can't get it to work. I believe the HTML is proper, but whenever I click on the element that should trigger the collapse, I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error in the console, pointing to the custom.js file which contains the `$('.collapse').collapse()` function. I assumed that I'm just enqueueing the scripts in the wrong order, but everything seems okay to me:

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-jquery','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', '', '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' , 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('bootstrap-jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', '', '1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700', false );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Am I missing something important, as I really can't figure it out. :/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses jQuery (and others) in noConflict mode, meaning that `$` isn't automatically available. To use `$` in your jQuery script, wrap your code in this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
    // [ your code goes here ]
} );
```

Reference: [the User Contributed Note from 'bcworkz' on the manual page for `wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#user-contributed-notes)

Also note: you shouldn't try to load a new jQuery (which is what your `bootstrap-jquery` seems to be doing, if I'm reading this right). Instead, add `jquery` to the dependencies:

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' , 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', '', '1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700', false );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Comment: This did the trick, thank you!

Comment: If this worked for you, please take a moment to mark it as the accepted answer. That will help others who may be having the same problem as you. (It'll increase my site karma, too, but that's secondary.)